# Find all devices on local network

Tags: vb.net

Looking for a faster way to find all devices connected to a network.  Below is the code I tried.  It is slow and does not pick up all devices.  I have a few Raspberry Pi connected and the loop does not find them.

```
Dim i As Integer
    Dim strIPAddress As String
    Dim lstAddresses As System.Net.IPHostEntry

    For i = 1 To 255
        Try
            strIPAddress = "192.168.33." & i
            lstAddresses = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strIPAddress)
            Console.WriteLine(strIPAddress & " " & lstAddresses.HostName)

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next i
```

Comment: [Did you see this ?](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889483/How-to-List-all-devices-info-on-your-WLAN-router) You have to ping all ranges and note that one which are responding and alive.

Comment: I had not seen your link.  That was a big help thank you

Comment: tell me if you face any difficulty.

Comment: The link you shared answered all my questions.  Thank you

Comment: Great. so tick my answer. It will help me to get enough reputation to post bounties in my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cab easily find out **how many peoples are using your wifi**. I found this great article:
[How to List all devices info on your WLAN /router Programmatically in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/889483/How-to-List-all-devices-info-on-your-WLAN-router)
It's in **Csharp** but you can easily convert it to **Visual Basic** using [converter.telerik.com](https://converter.telerik.com)